# Electric motor for opening gate?

Tags: electrical, installation, electric-motor, gates, gate-post

Our gate looks like this. It opens to the outside.

So I'm looking for an electric motor that I can install to open it by remote. But I have no idea where they're sold.

This gate used to have a motor on the top that would push the two gates and pull them back to close. If I remember correctly, the motor had two "arms" that would connect to each side.

But I've been searching the web and haven't found the appropriate motor.

Any help is appreciated.

NOTE: I cannot add motors on the side. My car won't fit if I put them there and my building doesn't permit it.
[image]

Comment: Does the area have a ceiling above it on the inside?

Comment: It doesn't have a ceiling, but something can be easily soldered/attached to hold a motor on top.

Comment: Yeah you've got us going in circles here because you're aware there was a unit before, but you have been mum on how it was attached.  That's very important info.

Comment: I have no idea how it was attached. I remember there was one on top but I was 6 then so I don't know how it was attached.

Comment: Because what I keep thinking is conventional garage door opener, and cleverly sized rod  linkage from the shoe to the top of the gates.  That, however, would require some sort of "top" to attach the opener to.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know how these motors are called? That way I can look at it at everyone's favorite online store. I tried searching for them there, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Try "Garage door opener".  Of course the linkage to the gate would be custom.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure why you’re having trouble finding a source. They’re called electric gate openers and if you have electricity already going to your gate, they’re easy to install. In remote locations, you can get solar powered ones.

[image: electric gate opener google search]

Comment: I cannot add motors on the side: My car won't fit if I put them there and my building doesn't permit it.

Comment: If you can’t add any of the motors that are displayed above or elsewhere, I don’t know how you can have a motorized gate.